# Is it possible to build a dynamic task list in nodejs Async (waterfall, series, etc...)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, asynchronous, async.js

I am pulling information from some collections in mongo that contain node and edge data. First i must get the node so i can grab its edges. Once i have a list of edges i then go back out and grab more nodes (etc.. based on a depth value). The following code is an loose example of how i am attempting to use async.waterfall and the task list.

Initially i have only a single task but once i make my first query i add to the task array. Unfortunately this does not seem to register with async and it does not continue to process the tasks i am adding.

Is there a better way to do this?

```
var async = require('async')
var mongoose = require('mongoose')
var _ = requrie('underscore')

var Client = this.Mongo.connect(/*path to mongo*/)
var Node = mongoose.Schema({
    id : String,
    graph_id : String
})
var Edge = mongoose.Schema({
    id : String,
    source_id : String,
    destination_id : String
})
var Nodes = Client.model('myNode', Node)
var Edges = Client.model('myEdge', Edge)
var funcs = []
var round = 1
var depth = 2

var query = {
    node : {
        id : '12345'
    },
    edge : {
        id : '12345'   
    }
}

var addTask = function(Nodes, Edges, query, round, depth) {
    return function(callback) {
    queryData(Nodes, Edges, query, function(err, node_list) {
        if(depth > round) {
             round++
             function_array.push(addTask(Nodes, Edges, query, round, depth))
        }
    })
}
}

var queryData = function(Nodes, Edges, query, cb) {
async.waterfall([
    function(callback) {
        Nodes.find(query.node, function(err, nodes) {
            var node_keys = _.map(nodes, function(node) {
                 return node.id  
            })
            callback(null, nodes, node_keys)  
        })
    },
    function(nodes, node_keys, callback) {
        query.edge.$or = [ {'source_id' : {$in:node_keys}}, {'destination_id' : {$in:node_keys}} ]
        Edges.find(query.edge, function(err, edges) {
            var edge_keys = _.map(edges, function(edge) {
                if(edge['_doc']['source_id'] != query.node.id) {
                     return edge['_doc']['source_id']
                } else {
                     return edge['_doc']['destination_id']
                }
                callback(null, nodes, edges, node_keys, edge_keys)
            })
        })
    }
], function(err, nodes, edges, node_keys, edge_keys) {
    // update the results object then...
    cb(null, _.uniq(edge_keys)
 })
}

var function_array = []
function_array.push(addTask(Nodes, Edges, query, round, depth))

async.waterfall(function_array, function(err) {
    Client.disconnect()
    //this should have run more than just the initial task but does not
})
```

--------------------- UPDATE ---------------------------

So after playing around with trying to get Async waterfall or series to do this by adding trailing functions I decided to switch to using async.whilst and am now happy with the solution.

```
function GraphObject() {
  this.function_array = []
}

GraphObject.prototype.doStuff = function() {
  this.function_array.push(this.buildFunction(100))
  this.runTasks(function(err) {
     console.log('done with all tasks')
  }
}

GraphObject.prototype.buildFunction = function(times) {
  return function(cb) {
    if(times != 0) {
      this.function_array.push(this.buildFunction(times - 1))
    }
    cb(null)
  }
}

GraphObject.prototype.runTasks = function(cb) {
  var tasks_run = 0
  async.whilst(
    function(){
      return this.function_array.length > 0
    }.bind(this),
    function(callback) {
      var func = this.function_array.shift()
      func.call(this, function(err) { 
        tasks_run++
        callback(err) 
      })
    }.bind(this),
    function(err) {
      console.log('runTasks ran '+tasks_run+' tasks')
      if(err) {
        cb(500)
      }
      cb(null)
    }.bind(this)
  )
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A task in your function_array can only add a new task to the array provided it is NOT the last task in the array.

In your case, your function_array contained only 1 task. That task itself cannot add additional tasks since it's the last task.

The solution is to have 2 tasks in the array. A startTask to bootstrap the process, and a finalTask that is more of a dummy task. In that case,

`function_array = [startTask, finalTask];`

Then startTask would add taskA, taskB will add task C and eventually

`function_array = [startTask, taskA, taskB, taskC, finalTask];`

The sample code below that illustrates the concepts.

```js
    var async = require('async');
    var max = 6;

    var nodeTask = function(taskId, value, callback){
        var r = Math.floor(Math.random() * 20) + 1;
        console.log("From Node Task %d: %d", taskId, r);

        // add an edge task
        if (taskId < max) {
            function_array.splice(function_array.length-1, 0, edgeTask);
        }

        callback(null, taskId + 1, value + r);
    };

    var edgeTask = function(taskId, value, callback){
        var r = Math.floor(Math.random() * 20) + 1;
        console.log("From Edge Task %d: %d", taskId, r);

        // add a node task
        if (taskId < max) {
            function_array.splice(function_array.length-1, 0, nodeTask);
        }

        callback(null, taskId + 1, value + r);
    };

    var startTask = function(callback) {
        function_array.splice(function_array.length-1, 0, nodeTask);
        callback(null, 1, 0);
    };

    var finalTask = function(taskId, value, callback) {
        callback(null, value);
    };

    var function_array = [startTask, finalTask];

    async.waterfall(function_array, function (err, result) {
        console.log("Sum is ", result);
    });
```

Comment: This is exactly the solution Kelvin thank you! Is there a section in the Async API that describes the difference of the "final" task in a task list from the others? Might be helpful to link it in the solution if there is.

Comment: Not in the API docs, rather it is in the [source] (https://github.com/caolan/async/blob/master/lib/async.js#L490). I actually worked on a hunch, wrote some sample code to check, and went to check the source. The source lines of interest are somewhere from 490 to 499.

Comment: Running into odd behavior after implementing the "final function" fix. Now the async.waterfall results callback is firing multiple times. Going to look into the source but it makes no sense.

Comment: Are your tasks calling the right callback? With nesting, it's easy to call the wrong callback. Separately, using async#waterfall may not be the best option. After you get a node and grab its edges, can you use async#each to process the edge task?

Comment: Yes that was my problem. I had the wrong callback kicking off.